# Facing issues while initializing list

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to initialize a list of type *Movie* in class other than *Movie* while both the classes are in the same namespace. Code is mentioned underneath:

```
namespace MovieListCaseStudy
{
    class Movie
    {
        private int id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        private float duration;

        public float Duration
        {
            get { return duration; }
            set { duration = value; }
        }
        private float price;

        public float Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }
        }
    }
}

******

namespace MovieListCaseStudy
{
    class BusinessLogic
    {
        List<Movie> movielist = new List<Movie>();
        {
            {Id=1, Name="pk", Duration=2, Price=200}

        };
    }
}
```

the problem is that Id, Name etc. attributes are not being identified in the *BusinessLogic* class. Kindly help.

Comment: Side note: durations should by `public TimeSpan Duration {get;set;}` and price (as all money related values) should be `public decimal Price {get;set;}`.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing `new Movie()`:

```
List<Movie> movielist = new List<Movie>()
{
    new Movie() { Id=1, Name="pk", Duration=2, Price=200 }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing semi colon, and as per @Marcin, construct with `new Movie()`. Also note that default constructor parenths `()` are optional with initializers:

```
class BusinessLogic
{
    List<Movie> movielist = new List<Movie>
    {
        new Movie {Id=1, Name="pk", Duration=2, Price=200}
    };
}
```

As an aside, another shorthand is possible with `Array` initialization, although in this case it would require an additional `.ToList()` conversion which would be less efficient in this case:

```
class BusinessLogic
{
    List<Movie> movielist = new [] // No type needed, will be inferred
    {
        new Movie {Id=1, Name="pk", Duration=2, Price=200}
    }
    .ToList();
}
```